# Python: how can I treat the currency pair same as the one formed in reversed order?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

I would like to group the rows by currency pairs but I got some problem. From the inputs, for the first two rows, USDGBP and GBPUSD are actually referring to the same currency pair but the order of currencies is reversed. How can I treat them as the same and sum the VR column by same currency pair? Many thanks!

The inputs can be found below:

```
  Qualifier FirstCurrency SecondCurrency            VR
0    USDGBP           USD            GBP  50000
1    GBPUSD           GBP            USD  60000
2    BRLUSD           BRL            USD  90000
3    EURQAR           EUR            QAR  30000
4    HKDKRW           HKD            KRW -10000
5    CNYSGD           CNY            SGD  20000
6    RUBTRY           RUB            TRY -14570
7    KRWBRL           KRW            BRL  28650
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make a `tuple` after sirting the currencies like

```py
df['grpupable'] = df['Qualifier'].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted([x[:3], x[3:]])))
```

**Example:** Now you can group them like

```
df.groupby(['grpupable'])['VR'].sum()
```

```
grpupable
(BRL, KRW)     28650
(BRL, USD)     90000
(CNY, SGD)     20000
(EUR, QAR)     30000
(GBP, USD)    110000
(HKD, KRW)    -10000
(RUB, TRY)    -14570
```

**UPDATE:**
To change the `FirstCurrency` and `LastCurrency` use. Or you can make a new column

```py
df['FirstCurrency'] = df['grpupable'].str[0]
df['SecondCurrency'] = df['grpupable'].str[1]
# or
# df['CurrencyA'] = df['grpupable'].str[0]
# df['CurrencyB'] = df['grpupable'].str[1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping! How can I turn the tuple df['grpupable'] into df after summing up the VR? I would like to separate the tuple into two currency columns for further calculation afterwards.